# Angular ngFor cannot render entire data

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I fetch data from api by **resolver** before loading component, also can see whole data in console and `{{ data.length }}` prints correct 100 number as well, but `ngFor` renders random amount of data about 20

```js
// data.component.ts

data: BooksData[];

ngOnInit(): void{
  this.route.data.subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data) // prints entire data correctly, data: Array(100)
      
      this.data = data;
    }
  )
}
```

```html
{{ data.length }} <!-- 100 -->

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let d of data">{{ d.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

i also tried slice pipe `*ngFor="let d of data | slice:0:(data.length-1)"` but same result

Comment: Since none of the guesses being posted as answers are helping you, I suggest you recreate the issue in https://stackblitz.com/, so we can see any errors in the console or in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax problem in the interpolation of `data.title`

```html
{{ data.length }} <!-- 100 -->

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let d of data">{{ data.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

Should be

```html
{{ data.length }} <!-- 100 -->

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let d of data">{{ d.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks @noririco for reply, it was typo here, response is same and cannot load entire data

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue `data.title` should be `d.title`

.html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let d of data | async">{{ d.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thans @Shariq, i have error now, `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object], [object Object]`

Comment: can you pls share this.data object?

Comment: and also share slice pipe

Comment: you need to change here also `d.length` : `*ngFor="let d of data | slice:0:(d.length-1)"`

Comment: rendered value in console.log: `0: {name: "nameA", author: "aA", price: 22} ...`

Comment: I already mentioned slice pipe: `*ngFor="let d of data | slice:0:(data.length-1)"`

Answer (score 0):

You already know now what is the problem from above comments.

i.e **data.tile** need to changed to **d.title**

If you want you can use below **more readable code**

```
books$: BooksData[];

ngOnInit(): void{
  this.books$ = this.route.data;
}
```

In html

```
<ul *ngIf="books$ | async as books">
  <li *ngFor="let book of books">
    {{ book.title }}
  </li>
</ul>
```